# Put multiple lines with special characters into clip using windows batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, currently I've tried to do it like this:

```
@echo off
(
    echo <script type=&quot;syntaxhighlighter&quot; class=&quot;brush: csharp&quot;><![CDATA[
    echo ]]></script>
) | clip
```

I also tried to encapsulate each line with "", but this way quotes are printed too.
Putting ^ character before each of the special characters seem to break the script completely. Like this:

```
echo ]]^>^</script^>
```

Comment: You need to escape the ampersands with carets too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this method:

```
@echo off
< NUL (
    set /P "=<script type=&quot;syntaxhighlighter&quot; class=&quot;brush: csharp&quot;><![CDATA["
    echo/
    set /P "=]]></script>"
    echo/
) | clip
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Altought I don't understand how :(